# Object expected error occurred in asp.net/jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Getting Object Expected Error in following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#TextBox2").keyup(function () {
      var a = $("#TextBox1").val();
      var b = $("#TextBox2").val();
      var sum = a + b;
      $("#TextBox3").val(sum);
   });
});
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Check TextBox1 or TextBox2 or TextBox3 contain in your code. Post your html code.

Comment: Try like this $("ID$='TextBox1').val()

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wqmez86L/) (perhaps maybe not how you expected, but I don't receive an error.)

Comment: It's working for me too. No error. Of course `1+2=12` may require some tweaking, like `parseInt()` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[ID$='TextBox2']").keyup(function () {
                var a = $("[ID$='TextBox1']").val();
                var b = $("[ID$='TextBox2']").val();
                var sum = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
                $("[ID$='TextBox3']").val(sum);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're incorrectly referencing an ID, or possibly all of them.

Check the ID's on your text boxes and make sure they're what you are looking for. They should look like :

```
<input type="text" id="TextBox1">
    <input type="text" id="TextBox2">
        <input type="text" id="TextBox3">
```

Also, if you wanted to add the text box values as integers and not strings, you just need a couple things.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TextBox2").keyup(function () {
            var a = parseInt($("#TextBox1").val());
            var b = parseInt($("#TextBox2").val());
            var sum = a + b;
            $("#TextBox3").val(sum);
        });
    });
```